# How can I correctly do a binary switch statement in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, libgdx, switch-statement

I am working on a game and I need to convert my binary tile id set into a switch statement so I can grab the correct tile from the sprite sheet.

I need to convert this list which contains all the possible tiles I would need from 255 to just 48 or so Tiles into a integer that I can use to get my tile id.

Can I get some help on starting this statement?

Also a x means that it doesn't matter what bit is set there.

EDIT: Should also say that this is a 8 bit number DCBA4321

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recomment to create a static array of 256 values for each possible combination like this:

```
static final int[] DCBA4321_TO_VALUE = {
    // 0000
    47, 44, 36,343, 37, 14, 35, 32, 45, 34, 15, 40, 42, 41, 33, 38,
    // 0001
    28, 28, 27, 27, 26, 26, 23, 23, 28, 28, 27, 27, 26, 26, 23, 23, 
    // 0010
    21, 21, 21, 21, 24, 24, 24, 24, 16, 16, 16, 16, 30, 30, 30, 30,
    // 0011
     1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  3,  3,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  3,  3,  3, 
    ...
};
```

Having such array you can simply join your DCBA and 4321 values using bitwise shift and add and map it to value. This seems to be the fastest approach for me

```
int getValue(int DCBA, int num) {
    return DCBA4321_TO_VALUE[(DCBA << 4)+num];
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting and does seem very fast. So would the next line in the hard coded values be

21 21 24 24 16 16 30 30?

What about the next row?

1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3?

Comment: Added two more rows to the answer. You have a convenient "Lower bits sum" column which gives a hint which 4321 values should be mapped to the target value. For example, "0-3, 8-11" means that we should have 8 ones in the row: in positions 0-3 and in positions 8-11.

Comment: Makes perfect since now thanks! I'm going to try this and another method and see how it turns out.

Comment: Seems that your DCBA is already shifted. In this case you should just add them: replace `(DCBA << 4)+num` with `DCBA+num`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you study Java's bitwise operators: [Click Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

```
class BitDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bitmask = 0x000F;
    int val = 0x2222;
    // prints "2"
    System.out.println(val & bitmask);
  }
}
```

Once you've masked the value, you can determine correct tile to grab.

Comment: Would I still be using a switch statement?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a mathematical formula for going from `dcba4321` to the target value you will have to do something like the following. I have broken it into sub-part to help support readability and maintenance.

```
byte dcba = dcba4312 & 0b11110000 >> 4
byte _4321 dcba4321 & 0b00001111;

switch (dcba) {
case 0b0000:
  return dcba0(_4321);
case 0b001:
  return dcba1(_4321);
...
  rest of the dcba cases;
...
}

dcba0(byte _4321) {
  switch (_4321) {
    case 0:
      return 47;
    case 1:
      return 44;
    ....
      rest of the cases
    ....
  }
}

....
rest of the dcbaX methods
....
```

Comment: I will try this one out and a couple below and test performance. Because it seems that there are many ways to do this. Learning a lot on this one. :)